# Why isn't the eigenvector of $T:P\rightarrow P$ defined by the derivative $e^x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In this question,

> Define $T:\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$ by $Tp=p'.$ Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$

where $\mathcal{P}$ is the space of all polynomials over $\mathbf{R}$, my answer was

> $$T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots)=\lambda(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\cdots)$$
> has the solution $a_0=\lambda a_1$, $a_1=2\lambda a_2$, $a_2=3\lambda a_3$, etc. which has the eigenvector
> $$1+x+x^2/2+x^3/3!+\cdots$$
> and the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.

But this does not appear in the solutions I've found, such as [Define $T:P(R)->P(R)$ by $Tp=p'.$ Find all eigen values and eigenvectors of T](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740924/define-tpr-pr-by-tp-p-find-all-eigen-values-and-eigenvectors-of-t).

What's wrong with my answer? It doesn't say that the polynomial is finite.

Comment: Because that isn't a polynomial. It would be an eigenvector in a bigger vector space that contains convergent power series, for example.

Comment: A polynomial by definition has finitely many terms.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thank you that is precisely the error I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polynomial has finitely many terms by definition.